# Why set `group_concat_max_len` below the maximum?

Tags: mysql, group-concatenation

MySQL 5.5.28 on Ubuntu 12.04

If the result is longer than `group_concat_max_len` then the result is gracelessly truncated.

Currently I have a script that tries to check the required length ahead of time and sets `group_concat_max_len` to be large enough.

But the checking adds extra queries. Is there any downside to just setting `group_concat_max_len` to the maximum value? The upside is fewer queries.

Comment: The question seems to be "If I set it too high, will I run out of RAM and crash, or something?".  Meanwhile, 1024 bytes is a trivial amount, and there seems to be no need to ever set it below that.

Comment: @RickJames RAM, CPU, etc, yes. “Will the query take a long time or use up a large part of system resources?”

Comment: But, if you say 1G, does it immediately use 1G, or does it start with a small value and work its way up if needed?

Comment: I have a similar script.  I wanted to account for 1M 32 character strings.  I was at first suprised to see that they took up 329999999 bytes in the group_concat buffer.  The moral of this story is don't forget to account for the commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate this question is a bit old now, but in case someone finds it and is wondering, one downside of setting the maximum (or an otherwise very large) value is that group_concat can return a blob rather than a varchar. Suggestions [elsewhere](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/11/why-group_concat-returns-blob/) say to set group_concat_max_len to 512 to make it always return a varchar rather than a blob. I tend to just cast it to char where necessary though.

Answer (score 5):

As per MySQL BOL [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)

> The maximum value for **`group_concat_max_len`** for 64-bit is
>   **`18446744073709551615`**
>
> &
>
> The maximum value for **`group_concat_max_len`** for 32-bit is
>   **`4294967295`**

The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the **`group_concat_max_len`** system variable, which has a **`default value of 1024`**. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of **`max_allowed_packet`**. The syntax to change the value of **`group_concat_max_len`** at `runtime` is as follows, where val is an `unsigned integer`:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

**Note:** The `maximum permitted` result length in **`bytes`** for the **`GROUP_CONCAT()`** function. The default is **`1024`**.

As MySQL documented blog [Here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/but-i-do-want-mysql-to-say-error) Using **`GROUP_CONCAT`** with a small **`group_concat_max_len`** setting? Your result will be `silently truncated` (make sure to check the warnings though).

As MySQL Blog by **`@Shlomi Noach`** [Here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/those-oversized-undersized-variables-defaults) **`group_concat_max_len`**: This parameter limits the `maximum` text length of a `GROUP_CONCAT` concatenation result. It defaults to `1024`. I think this is a very low value. I have been using `GROUP_CONCAT` more and more, recently, to solve otherwise difficult problems. And in most cases, `1024` was just `too low`, resulting in [silent](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/but-i-do-want-mysql-to-say-error) (Argh!) truncating of the result, thus returning incorrect results. It is interesting to learn that the maximum value for this parameter is limited by **`max_packet_size`**. I would suggest, then, that this parameter should be altogether removed, and have the **`max_packet_size`** `limitation` as the `only limitation`. Otherwise, I'd like it to have a **`very large default value`**, in the order of a few **`MB`**.

For Further your ref [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) & [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553823/what-is-the-maximum-allowance-for-group-concat-max-len-in-mysql)

Comment: My question is a bit more nuanced and granular. I’ve already read the manual so your copy-paste job doesn’t help me. Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: @Buttle Butkus,Each and every application they have some set of default environment variable parameter size, min and max.if you shall not meet there define threshold parameter limit, then that application behave abruptly way.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know about performance impact of changing this setting. Would making it large impact ALL queries or just the ones where large concatenations occur?

Comment: @ButtleButkus, you know that "SET GLOBAL" means the setting will affect all other MySQL connections on your server, and the setting will even persist after your current session is done, until you set it to something else? You might want to use "SET SESSION" if you only want the value to affect your current session.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know those things and they have nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Thank you MySQL for truncating data silently when exceeded `group_concat_max_len` leading to lots of time wasted when investigating pretty weird bug.